# GetResponse API intragration with Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, getresponse

I have a Yii Application and I want to integrate it with getResponse API. I downloaded a getresponsapi.php from github: https://github.com/GetResponse/getresponse-api-php

I integrated this file accordingly to Yii, I extended the GetResponse class with CComponent and I've set the $api_key = 'https://mywebsite.com/'.

Then in one of my page I tried go display all Contacts with the following code:

```
$get_response = new GetResponse('my-api-key-here');
print '<pre>';
print_r($get_response);
print '</pre>';
$contacts = $get_response->getContacts();
print '<pre>';
print_r($contacts);
print '</pre>';
```

This code returns only an empty object. I don't thinks this is a configuration error because it would give me a getresponse error with an error code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_response = new GetResponse('my-api-key-here');
```

You should put into `$get_response` your API KEY.

API KEY you can get here https://app.getresponse.com/manage_api.html

```
require_once('GetResponseAPI3.class.php');
$key_ip = 'PUT_YOUR_KEY_HERE';

$api = new GetResponse($key_ip);

// Connection Testing
$ping = $api->ping();
var_dump($ping);
```

Its work for me now.